# When is a transaction signature checked in a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, signature

In the Solidity tutorial and examples here, I don't see any signature checking. In particular, in the contracts provided there, they don't check whether the sender of a message is actually the person who claims to be. So, my question is:

**Question**: In contracts written in Solidity,  do we usually check the signature (of the message sender)?  if yes, when?

Answer (score 3):

The Ethereum protocol is defined such that you can trust that the sender is really set to the owner of the account (in Solidity, that means you can trust `msg.sender` is already validated). Below are some sections of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) which define this protocol.

Specifically, a transaction includes several parameters (`v`, `r`, and `s`) that allow everyone to validate the signature.

[image: transaction signature values]

Transactions are only considered valid if the signature is valid. (see item 2)

[image: transaction validity]

Blocks that include invalid transactions will be rejected as invalid by protocol-respecting miners and peers. (see item 2)

[image: block validity]

Miners that attempt to include a transaction with an invalid signature anyway (violating the protocol) will waste their resources: future miners will not build on top of the invalid block, and the malicious miner will never get to spend their block reward.

Comment: It'd be better to quote the text, instead of using screenshots of the yellow paper since it's blurry and hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

The address of the sender of a transaction populates `msg.sender`.

You can check if this address matches a particular address in your function definitions. You do this when you need to. I.E When your functionality requires a specific user to have called it.

You can abstract this 'checking' functionality into a [modifier](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html) to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks. I think if we just compare msg.sender with some address we have in mine, the problem would not be solved. I think we need to see if it has the private key related to msg.sender. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. You can't sign a transaction without the private key. I.E. The function is only executed and msg.sender is only set if the transaction has been signed correctly.

Comment: Right, that means the contract doesn't need to worry about it, and this verification is done by the (full) nodes and miner. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. To all extents and purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Signatures are checked automatically by the EVM prior to a contract's execution. There's no need to double-check, nor is it possible. In fact, if `msg.sender` is another contract, it doesn't even make sense.

It is, however, possible to manually verify a signature with [`ecrecover()`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions). This is useful for state channels, as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol checks for you. It's not a valid transaction unless signed by `msg.sender`. So, nicely, not a concern.

Many apps need to check for privileges (is this the admin?) so they can check the `msg.sender` against an access control list of some kind.

A little off topic, but related. `tx.origin` is a no-go in my opinion because the sender can spoofed in ways that are not possible with `msg.sender`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which protocol do you mean by "The protocol checks for you"?

Comment: Ethereum, miners, verifiers. It's just not a valid transaction unless it's signed by the `msg.sender` and everyone knows it.