# Is possible to send tx by someone else

Tags: solidity, raw-transaction

I mean if I have address A and no ethers on it.
And I will construct valid tx & and sign it with my privkey.
Can I send this raw signed tx to my friend with address B, and he will push it to the network.
He need to sign it, and gas will be taken from his B address, but in contract `msg.sender` will be set as address A, who initially signed this tx.

Is possible scenario like above?
I assume it is not at this moment.
But do Vitalik`s team want to implement something like that to be possible?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24478/when-is-a-transaction-signature-checked-in-a-contract/24491#24491

Answer (score 5):

No. This is not possible.

A transaction is signed using a private key. `msg.sender` is set to the address that corresponds to that private key.

You can send the signed transaction data to anyone, and they can submit it on your behalf to the chain. The person who signed the data still pays for the gas, and is the `msg.sender`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation to post this as a comment to Thomas Clowes answer, so I will post it as a separate answer. Since the transaction is submitted by person B, wouldn't tx.origin point to the address of the one who signed it? Otherwise, it is not possible with the technology Ethereum currently implements.